Skill Alexa - API getEndpointEnumerationServiceClient does not find devices
I'm developing a skill with Alexa Smart Home and Alexa Skill Kit. This skill needs to find the devices available in the user’s account.
I tried using the endpointenumerationserviceclient method (link here), but it always returns empty, even though I have devices in the account.
What can I do to return devices?
Thank you for your help.

I suspect that this is not possible.
With "Endpoints" ASK doesn't seem to refer to devices.
To interact with other devices the Smart Home Skill API is offered, as explained in this similar question. You may have to implement a "Smart Device Manufacturer Cloud" application that manages the connected devices.
